# Could not enable the selected dates of jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to enable the selected dates from jQuery UI datepicker but in some cases it could not enable. I am providing my code below.

```
 var vid='06-11-2018,13-11-2018,20-11-2018,27-11-2018';
var enableDays = vid.split(',');
          $(".depdate").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths:3,
            minDate: 0,
            beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays,
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
              //$(".depdate").val(dateText);
            }
          });
          function enableAllTheseDays(date){
            var sdate = $.datepicker.formatDate( 'd-m-yy', date);
            if($.inArray(sdate, enableDays) != -1) {
                return [true];
            }
            return [false];
          }
```

Here my problem is the dates like `06-11-2018` could not enable and I need to enable those dates present with comma separated string.

Comment: could you please try the 'dd-MM-yyyy' format? It is possible that your sdate is not properly formatted

Comment: @Sorin87bv : Its not working. all dates getting disabled.

Comment: I run a test, the proper format is dd-mm-yy and it worked. The reason this worked but not yours is that dates like '06' are transformed in '6' with 'd-m-yy' format and obviously the strings are different at that point

Answer (score 1):

could you please try this code.

```
var vid="29-12-2018,30-12-2018,20-01-2019,27-01-2019";
var enableDays = vid.split(',');
          $("#date1").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths:3,
            minDate: 0,
            beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays,
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
              //$(".depdate").val(dateText);
            }
          });
          function enableAllTheseDays(date){
            var sdate = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd-mm-yy", date);
            console.log(enableDays.indexOf(sdate));
            if(enableDays.indexOf(sdate) > -1) {
                     return [true];
            }
            return [false];
          }
```